# Simplest MDX request?

Tags: mdx, business-intelligence

What is the simplest [MDX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_Expressions) request?

I want to test whether my MDX endpoint answers correctly to a very simple request.
In SQL, I would say `SELECT 1;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This query will display your first measure against the top level of the first dimension it finds. All you need to specify is the name of your cube. It will return one number.

```
 SELECT {Dimensions(0).defaultMember} ON ROWS, 
 {[Measures].defaultMember} ON COLUMNS 
 FROM [NameOfCube]
```

Comment: Perfect! This request only requires to know a cube's name, which is not much to ask.

Answer (score 7):

I guess the simplest MDX request would be : SELECT FROM cubeName

Comment: This would be the correct answer, it is simpler than the currently accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that you can bring back constants in an MDX query - you've piqued my interest.  I would just fire off a query against a base measure in your cube, if you don't specify any additional axis you'll get a single value result set.

```
SELECT [MeasureGroup].[Measure]
  FROM [Cube]
```

Pretty basic - here's MS guide to the [basic syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144785.aspx) for an MDX statement.

Comment: That's quite simple, but I will wait a bit before accepting, to see if any constant-based answer comes up. Not requiring knowledge about the existing data's structure would be ideal.

Comment: I expect you can bring back a constant in MDX, with something like WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Forty Two] AS '42' perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH MEMBER Test AS 1
SELECT Test ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube]
```

Constants all the way down.

Comment: I get errors when running this... Is this an MDX request, or just a fragment?

Comment: @Nicolas, this works fine in MS SSAS 2008, you will need to swap [Cube] for your own cube name. What error do you get?

Comment: @Meff: Mondrian Error:Failed to parse query 'WITH MEMBER Test AS 1
SELECT Test ON COLUMNS FROM [SalesAnalysis]
'

Mondrian Error:Error while parsing MDX statement 'WITH MEMBER Test AS 1
SELECT Test ON COLUMNS FROM [SalesAnalysis]
'

Mondrian Error:Hierarchy for calculated member '[Test]' not found

Comment: @Nicolas, I'm not familiar with Mondrian, so this could be a difference in provider syntax. Try enclosing the 1 in single quotes? If that fails, then perhaps this will only work in Microsoft's version of MDX :s

Comment: @Nicolas, unless it requires the MDX to be "WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Test] AS '1'
SELECT {[Measures].[Test]} ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube]" then I think it may be an MS MDX extension :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try MDSchema rowsets. Use select * from $system.Discover_Schema_Rowsets to find ones to choose among. I'm partial to this one:

select TOP 0 [CATALOG_NAME]
from $system.DBSCHEMA_CATALOGS

It returns over 1KB, but that's small for the XMLA endpoint.

However, I like this better; create a session-scoped calculated member (or set), which disappears after your command is executed. The response is very short:

PS C:> Invoke-ASCmd -Query "CREATE MEMBER [mycube].x AS 1" -Server myserver  -Database mydatabase

<return xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis"><root xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:empty"></root></return>